# Recommendation on Optical Sensor (being used for Fingerprint Scanning)

Tags: sensor

When I have researched available optical fingerprint sensor modules, every one comes with a processor that takes the sensor image data and processes it.  They all appear to keep the fingerprint data internal to the module, and only allow commands to be sent via UART in order to scan/store/compare.  Most appear similar to this [Adafruit Fingerprint Scanner](https://www.adafruit.com/product/751?gclid=EAIaIQobChMImaTD4uPn5gIVAeiGCh0t9QpUEAQYASABEgJ0bfD_BwE).  I am looking for an optical sensor that transmits *just* the raw image data so that I can process it myself.

I need this, as a part of my research is to recreate algorithms that identify/compare fingerprints.  As such, I want a module that I can interface with a processor, where the sensor module transmits the image data back to my own processor, and from there I can process the data as I so wish.

One alternative would be to purchase the Adafruit module, and then simply bypass the on-board processor in favor of my own, but I cannot seem to find any documentation on how the on-board processor communicates with the optical sensor.  I would need to know this in order to identify the communication standards being used to capture the data.  As such, I think my best alternative is to reach out for help in finding an optical sensor module that has proper documentation that I can reference, that is suitable for fingerprint scanning.

My background is in embedded design, but I have no prior knowledge of optical sensor modules.  If anyone has any familiarity with optical scanners, and has a recommendation for one that would be suitable for this application, I would very much appreciate hearing your thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/DY001fingerprint.pdf) for the Adafruit module indicates it's possible to download the image ("下载图像") using instruction code 0x0b.

The datasheet is in Chinese, so if you're not able to read it, it might take a bit of time, but most of the information should be there.